# Databinding not observe LiveData in ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-databinding, android-livedata

I am trying to use Data binding with LiveData in ViewModel. But when using Transformations.map functions not trigged without adding observers explicitly. Data binding in XML not generate observers for LiveData in ViewModel.

**LoginFragment.kt**

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {

    var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel? = null

    companion object {
        val TAG : String = "LoginFragment"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
    }


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentLoginBinding>(inflater, R.layout.fragment_login, container, false)
                .apply {
                    setLifecycleOwner(this@LoginFragment)
                    loginButton.setOnClickListener {
                        signInWithEmail()
                    }
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    /*private fun observeHomeFragmentUIDataLiveData() {
        homeViewModel?.homeFragmentUIDataLiveData?.observe(this, Observer {
            val email = it.email
            Toast.makeText(activity,email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
    }

    private fun observeLoginErrorEventLiveData() {
        homeViewModel?.loginErrorEventLiveData?.observe(this, Observer {
            Toast.makeText(activity,it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
    }*/

    /**
     * Sign In via Email
     */
    fun signInWithEmail(){
        val email = email_text_input_layout.editText?.text.toString()
        val password = password_text_input_layout.editText?.text.toString()

        var cancel : Boolean? = false
        var focusView : View? = null

        if(password.isEmpty()){
            password_text_input_layout.error = getString(R.string.this_field_is_required)
            focusView = password_text_input_layout
            cancel = true
        }

        if(email.isEmpty()){
            email_text_input_layout.error = getString(R.string.this_field_is_required)
            focusView = email_text_input_layout
            cancel = true
        }

        if(cancel!!){
            focusView?.requestFocus()
        }
        else{
            homeViewModel?.signInWithEmail(email,password)

            /*homeViewModel?.signInWithEmail(email,password)?.observe(this, Observer {
                val email = it
                Toast.makeText(activity,""+email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            })*/
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_login.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable name="homeViewModel" type="com.rramprasad.adminapp.HomeViewModel"/>
    </data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="LoginFragment">

<!-- Skipped some code for clarity -->

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/error_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{homeViewModel.loginErrorEventLiveData.value}"
        app:isGone="@{homeViewModel.isLoginSuccess}"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/password_text_input_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/login_button"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**HomeViewModel.kt**

```
class HomeViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val homeRepository: HomeRepository?

    init {
        homeRepository = HomeRepository()
    }

    // UI Data for HomeFragment
    val homeFragmentUIDataLiveData : MutableLiveData<HomeFragmentUIData> = MutableLiveData()

    // UI Data for LoginFragment
    val loginErrorEventLiveData : MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

    var isLoginSuccess: LiveData<Boolean>? = null

    fun signInWithEmail(email: String, password: String) : LiveData<Boolean>? {
        val signInResponseMutableLiveData : MutableLiveData<Any> = homeRepository?.signInWithEmail(email, password)!!

        isLoginSuccess = Transformations.map(signInResponseMutableLiveData) { signInResponse ->
            when (signInResponse) {
                (signInResponse is FirebaseUser) -> {
                    val firebaseUserEmail = (signInResponse as FirebaseUser).email
                    homeFragmentUIDataLiveData.value = HomeFragmentUIData(firebaseUserEmail ?: "")
                    return@map true
                }
                else -> {
                    loginErrorEventLiveData.value = signInResponse.toString()
                    return@map false
                }
            }
        }

        return isLoginSuccess
    }
}
```

**BindingAdapters.kt**

```
@BindingAdapter("isGone")
fun bindIsGone(view: View, isGone: Boolean) {
    view.visibility = if (isGone) {
        View.GONE
    } else {
        View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

**Android studio version:**

> ```
> Android Studio 3.2 RC 3
> Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.4987877, built on August 31, 2018
> JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 x86_64
> JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
> macOS 10.13.4
> ```

**build.gradle:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: your problem is exactly described here https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-beyond-the-viewmodel-reactive-patterns-using-transformations-and-mediatorlivedata-fda520ba00b7 in **solution :wire transformations during initialization**. suggest read up the entire blog and make changes

Comment: I am not able to understand Solution: wire transformations during initialization  for my case.

Comment: move your transfromation in initialization say constructor of your view model. check https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/ui/user/UserViewModel.kt for a sample

Comment: *"Transformations.map functions not trigged without adding observers explicitly."* - see [Transform LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata) and ^F `The transformations aren't calculated unless an observer is watching the returned LiveData object` - i already told you that you dont need `Transformations#*map` methods (nor `MediatorLiveData`)

Comment: ah. that makes sense.

Comment: @pskink he does have this  `setLifecycleOwner(this@LoginFragment)`.

Comment: @Raghunandan it is for databinding to work correctly with `LiveData` and is not connected with the main issue

Comment: @pskink got it the observer is commented in his code.

Comment: Yes I am trying to do without observers in fragment and do it from xml. We can do transformation on constructor but I will get source livedata from click event of login button and get response from repository. So do transformation in constructor is possible?

Comment: what constructor? did you see: `"The transformations aren't calculated unless an observer is watching the returned LiveData object"` i posted above?

Comment: Yes my aim is avoid using lot of observers in fragment. My assumption is, when use data binding in xml it generate observers internally for our LiveData in ViewModel.

Comment: Use `Transformation.switchmap` to connect view model and repository and that has to be in `init` block. This is because LiveData needs an active state which is given by `LifecycleOwner( activity/ fragment)` when initializing VM.

Comment: @Ramprasad Please have a look https://github.com/rohitsingh14101992/livedatamvvm/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/rohitsingh/news/ui/MainActivityViewModel.kt

Comment: @SangeetSuresh it is good..i try it...

Comment: check this solution 5 at https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/architecture-components-pitfalls-part-1-9300dd969808. I think you also need `binding.sethomeViewModel = homeViewModel`. so you don't need observers in your fragment

Comment: @SangeetSuresh If i move my Transformations to init block, i will not get source LiveData. Need to make sourceLiveData as "var" and declare globally. So is it makes all LiveData becomes var instead of val?

Comment: @Ramprasad It will not make all LiveData as var. If you want to apply `Transformation` to whichever LiveData make it as `var`. Another possible solution is initialize transformation when you are declaring a field so that you can use `val`